# Remove last digits from an int

Tags: javascript

Can't seem to find a good answer to this question. How do I remove the last 11 digits from an int?

The id could be one or more numbers in the beginning but there will always be 11 digits following the id. There will always be an id in the beginning. `{id}{11 digits}`.

```
var getId = function (digits) {
   // Do some stuff and return id
}

getId(110000000001); // Should return 1
getId(1110000000001); // Should return 11
getId(2010000000001); // Should return 20
```

Comment: divide and floor or toString and substring it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Divide by `1e11` and take the floor:

```
var stripped = Math.floor(id / 1e11);
```

This avoids conversion to/from a string representation.

Note that the nature of JavaScript numerics is such that your "raw" values (the values *with* the 11 useless digits) can't have more than 5 digits in addition to those 11 before you'll start running into precision problems. I guess if you never care about the low-order 11 digits that might not be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var str = 1100000000011; 
var res = str.toString().substr(0, str.toString().length - 11);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bTS57/2/)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your number to string and delete tailing digits:

```
digits.toString().replace(/\d{11}$/, '')
```

By the way, you better don't use ints (or to be precise, Numbers) because if number is greater than 2147483648 (by absolute value), it'll be represented internally as `double` resulting in precision loss. If don't need tailing digits, then it's okay — use division approach suggested in other answers (this one could break because of scientific notation). But if you want to keep all the data, you should represent your numbers with strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use division and 10^11 to do so.
Edit: my bad

Answer (score 1):

```
var getId = function (digits) {
   var id = parseInt((digits/(1e11)),0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the number to a string and slice the last 11 characters from the end

`parseInt( digits.toString().slice(0, -11) );`

Using `.slice( 0 , [ negative_number ]);` will slice `x` characters from the end of the string

More information on `.slice()` [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)